# Building a Docker with Multiple Proto - Proto File not found

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, protocol-buffers

I'm running with an issue where I can't build  Dockerfile that includes multiple proto files(server and text). The server proto is within the Dockerfile dir, but the text proto is within the Dockerfile parent. So I'm building the Dockerfile in the parent dir to COPY the text proto to the Docker build.

The Docker build complaining about `proto/text.proto: File not found.` even though I COPY the `proto/text.proto` to the exact location as `server/proto/server.proto`.

Here are all my files:

##### DockerFile

```
FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 golang:1.19.3-bullseye

# Install grpc
RUN go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.2 && \
    go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.28

WORKDIR /app
COPY server/. /app
COPY proto/text.proto /app/proto/text.proto

# Install protoc and zip system library
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip && \
    mkdir /opt/protoc && cd /opt/protoc && wget https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.7.0/protoc-3.7.0-linux-x86_64.zip && \
    unzip protoc-3.7.0-linux-x86_64.zip

# Copy the grpc proto file and generate the go module
RUN /opt/protoc/bin/protoc --go_out=/app/proto --proto_path=/app/proto --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=/app/proto --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative /app/proto/text.proto /app/proto/server.proto

EXPOSE 5051
RUN go build -o /server
ENTRYPOINT ["/server"]
```

##### Dir Tree

```
1.text
    ├── admin
    │   ├── Dockerfile
    │   ├── app.js
    │   ├── package.json
    │   └── web
    │       ├── html
    │       │   └── index.html
    │       └── resources
    ├── compose.yaml
    ├── db
    │   ├── Dockerfile
    │   ├── main.go
    │   ├── proto
    │   │   ├── db.pb.go
    │   │   ├── db.proto
    │   │   └── db_grpc.pb.go
    │   └── text.db
    ├── go.mod
    ├── go.sum
    ├── proto
    │   ├── text.pb.go
    │   └── text.proto
    └── server
        ├── Dockerfile
        ├── main.go
        ├── proto
        │   ├── server.pb.go
        │   ├── server.proto
        │   └── server_grpc.pb.go
        └── text
            ├── text.go
            └── text_test.go
```

I'm able to run the following protoc in the root `text` dir:

```
protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative proto/text.proto db/proto/db.proto server/proto/server.proto
```

And run the server locally, but I'm not able to build my Docker:

##### CMD

```
docker build -f server/Dockerfile -t server .
```

##### Error

```
=> ERROR [7/8] RUN /opt/protoc/bin/protoc --go_out=/app/proto --proto_path=/app/proto --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=/app/proto --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative   0.4s
------
 > [7/8] RUN /opt/protoc/bin/protoc --go_out=/app/proto --proto_path=/app/proto --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=/app/proto --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative /app/proto/text.proto /app/proto/server.proto:
#11 0.427 proto/text.proto: File not found.
#11 0.429 server.proto: Import "proto/text.proto" was not found or had errors.
#11 0.431 server.proto:25:5: "text.Status" seems to be defined in "text.proto", which is not imported by "server.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /opt/protoc/bin/protoc --go_out=/app/pro
```

###### text/server/proto

```
syntax="proto3";
package server;

import "proto/text.proto";
option go_package = "github.com/amb1s1/text/server/proto/server";

message SendMessageRequest {
    string token = 1;
    string phone = 2;
    string message = 3;
    bool dry_run = 4;
};

message SendMessageResponse {
    text.Status status = 1;
};

service Text {
    // SendMessage sents SMS message.
    rpc SendMessage(SendMessageRequest) returns (SendMessageResponse) {}
}
```

##### text/proto/

```
syntax="proto3";

package text;

option go_package = "github.com/amb1s1/text/proto";

enum Status {
    UNKNOW = 0;
    OK = 1;
    TOKENS_EXISTS = 2;
    TOKEN_NOT_FOUND = 3;
    FAILED_NOT_SENT= 4;
    DRY_RUN_OK = 5;
    ZERO_BALANCE = 6;
    WRONG_TOKEN = 7;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to list the copied files in the docker container's folder to check whether it's really there and has the proper permissions/the same permissions set? Another thing which might be unrelated but maybe had a similar cause: For a long time I had trouble to access files in a parent directy with `protoc` under Linux (tested with my Ubuntu system and in an Alpine docker), while it worked under MacOs. So `protoc` might still have some issues with permissions in a Linux environment.

Comment: Here is my files:

root@303e000dd8bf:/app/proto# ls

server.pb.go  server.proto  server_grpc.pb.go  server_pb.js  text.proto

root@303e000dd8bf:/app/proto# pwd
/app/proto

You see that protoc worked for the server.proto

Comment: I see, so `COPY proto/text.proto /app/proto/text.proto`  actually worked, that was what I was wondering. Are the permissions on `/app/proto/text.proto` and `/app/proto/server.proto` the same? You know, if you run `ls -l`. If they have the same permissions, does `cat /app/proto/text.proto` work (in case `cat` is available in the docker's linux)? Would it work if copied the `text.proto` from the same folder as `server.proto`? Just to single out whether it's the file itself or its location ...

Comment: `--proto_path=/app/proto` looks wrong to me (you are importing `proto/text.proto` so, adding the library path, that gives `/app/proto/proto/text.proto`). Either remove the `--proto_path` or set to `--proto_path=/app`.

Comment: Still not working, if this was the case how come server.proto worked? If the file is in the same directory. I used --proto_path=/app

Comment: I replicated the directory structure given above (just adding the `.proto` files) and got the same error you did with `--proto_path=/app/proto` but `protoc` completed successfully with `--proto_path=/app`.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I was testing in another dockerfile, thanks for taking the time to replicate the problem. Did you add something else on the Dockerfile because now I'm not able to build my Go binary. I will post another question if you did not add anything else to the Dockerfile.

Comment: No - I did not have your go sourcecode so my Dockerfile failed at the `go build` (which was expected). I'll add this as an answer in case it helps someone else.

Comment: As asides to the answer to your question but that may minimize future challenges, I consider anti-patterns to be (1) embedding protos (`.proto` and generated code) in implementations (`admin`, `db`, `server`); (2) generating stubs in Dockerfiles.

Comment: (1) `protos` represents interfaces that are often reused against implementations. Binding them into implementations. makes the implementations less emphatic, locks versioning (unnecessarily) and inhibits reuse.

Comment: (2) Generating stubs in Dockerfiles seems to be a good practice (the definition is the "source" not the generated code) but it seems problematic in a Dockerfile. Your application code is irrevocably bound to the stub code (which could change by `proto` **or** `protoc` changes). It's better to use the language's package management to pull versioned stubs (this is more easily achieved with distinct proto packages per #1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments; within your docker image you have the directory structure:

```
/app/proto/server.proto 
/app/proto/text.proto
```

`server.proto` imports `text.proto` with `import "proto/text.proto"`.

This means that `protoc` will be looking for a file called `proto/text.proto` within the import path. You specified `--proto_path=/app/proto` as an argument to `protoc` meaning that `protoc` will check for `/app/proto/proto/text.proto` which does not exist (hence the issue). To fix this remove the `--proto_path=/app/proto` (so `protoc` uses the working folder) or specify `--proto_path=/app`.